# Kotlin Array init function

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and have difficulty understanding how the [init function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html) works in context of an Array. Specifically, if I'm trying to make an array of `String` type using:

```
val a = Array<String>(a_size){"n = $it"}
```

1. This works, but what does `"n = $it"` mean? This doesn't look like the `init` function as it is within curly braces and not inside the parenthesis.
2. If I want an Array of `Int` what would the `init` function or the part inside the curly braces look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're calling a constructor with an initializer:

```
/**
 * Creates a new array with the specified [size], where each element is calculated by calling the specified
 * [init] function. The [init] function returns an array element given its index.
 */
public inline constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)
```

Thus, you're passing a function to the constructor which will get called for each element. The result of `a` will be

```
[
  "n = 0",
  "n = 1",
  ...,
  "n = $a_size"
]
```

If you just want to create an array with all `0` values, do it like so:

```
val a = Array<Int>(a_size) { 0 }
```

Alternatively, you can create arrays in the following way:

```
val a = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
val b = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: What if I don't want to initialize the Array with any values? Kotlin equivalent of this Java snippet `ArrayList<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);`

Comment: In Java this will result in a list with all `0` values. In Kotlin you will have to specify this explicitly.

Comment: I see. But I'm in the process of writing a twig template and I'm trying to generalize the array creation syntax for various datatypes. So I want something that reads, `Array<{{TYPE}}>(a_size) { {{GENERAL_INITIALIZER}} }`.

Is this possible with the current syntax?

Comment: You will either need to create an array with nullable values, or provide a default non-null value for the type.